# How to sum values in a column using conditional statements of other columns in a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe having 5 columns and 25552 rows. The dataframe structure as follows:

```
mydf.head(4)

station       date         Lat    Lon       prcp
USC00397992   1998-10-01   44.26  -99.44    0.5
USC00397993   1998-10-01   44.01  -100.35   1.2
USC00397994   1998-10-01   45.65  -97.12    1.1
USC00397995   1998-10-01   43.90  -99.52    0.7
```

There are many distinct stations in `station` column and the `date` column has dates range from 1998-10-01 to 1999-06-30. Also, each distinct station has distinct lat and Lon. The `prcp` column is a record of precipitations for respective dates. Now I want to find the sum of `prcp` values for each `station` date range from 1999-05-01 to 1999-05-07. I want output like this:

```
station       Lat      Lon     sum_from_May1_to_May7
 USC00397992  44.26  -99.44       2.5 (for instance)
  .             .       .           .
  .             .       .           .

  .
```

Comment: since you used the tag `groupby`, it means you're aware of its existence. What have you tried with `groupby`?

Comment: @Yuca I was able to pick distinct stations from station column using groupby but I couldn't crack date columns according to my needs.

Comment: @ychaulagain you might accept only one answer as the accepted one ;)I've noticed you've been going back and forth on that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you dont want to groupby with respect to lat long:

```
df[(df['date']>pd.Timestamp(1995,5,1)) & (df['date']<pd.Timestamp(1995,5,7))]\
     .groupby('station').agg({'prcp':'sum', 'Lat' :'first', 'Lon' :'first'})
```

Answer (score 1):

First filter your data frame

```
df2 = df.loc[(df.date >= '1999-05-01') & (df.date <= '1999-05-07)]
```

Then just straightforwardly

```
df2.groupby('station').prcp.sum()
```

If you don't want different `Lat` and `Lon` grouped together, then

```
df2.groupby(['station', 'Lat', 'Lon']).prcp.sum()
```